# difference between jpeg and exif image formats

Tags: images

could someone please tell me the difference between jpeg and exif image formats. I found a jpg image compressed using exif compression. Is this compression different to jpeg?

Comment: [EXIF](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Exif) is a format to add metadata to files (mostly pictures), [JPEG](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Jpeg) is a lossy image format, for storing photographs. I think reading the Wikipedia articles should clear things up, the two things are related but not really comparable.

Comment: @Tim, you might want to make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXIF is a chunk of data stored in image and sound files.  It can have in it different metadata, like camera settings used, time date, even gps location data. It is not of itself a compression method.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif

if you want to see or alter exif data in a file, http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ is one tool that can do that.

Answer (score 2):

[EXIF](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Exif) is a format to add metadata to files (mostly pictures), [JPEG](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Jpeg) is a lossy image format, for storing photographs. I think reading the Wikipedia articles should clear things up, the two things are related but not really comparable.